# ARC - How to manage those properties which needs to be unsafe_unretained?

Tags: ios, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

I am using ARC and i am declaring my ivar in my interface with

id itemDelegate;
I then declare the property:

`@property (nonatomic, weak) id<myAppDelegate> Delegate`;

In my implementation file I simply synthesize it as:

`@synthesize Delegate`;

However, I am getting the error:

"Existing ivar 'ItemDelegate' for _weak property 'itemDelegate' must be _weak".

Can anyone suggest the solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the iVar declaration, as it will be automatically created.

The problem is that the default ownership qualifier for iVars is `__strong`. Hence, `id itemDelegate` is the same as `__strong id itemDelegate`. If you declare the property as weak, you have a problem there. You need to use `__weak`. (or `__unsafe_unretained` if you need backwards compatibility for iOS 4.)

Comment: i removed it.. but its not working yet.. it still requires the property to be _unsafe_unretained.

Comment: Did you try a clean build? What is the error message? Are you targeting iOS 4?

Comment: hey thanks... i set the `@property(nonatomic,weak)id<MyAppdelegate>Delegate` and its working now... thanks @Fabian...